# Android handling click on notification

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-stack

I have this situation in my app: I have these activities

```
<activity
            android:name=".presentation.view.start.view.activity.StartActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.view.main.view.activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeMultiStep"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.view.firstScreen.view.activity.FirstScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeMultiStep"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.view.signup.view.activity.LoginViaPinActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeMultiStep" />
```

StartActivity acts as a sort of "router" based on the application state:

- If I am not logged in, it will launch FirstScreenActivity
- If I am logged in, it will launch LoginViaPinActivity, which will login the user based on some logic and then launch MainActivity. At the end of all, MainActivity will be at the root of the activities stack.

At some point the app will receive a notification, and when I tap it I want this:

if the app is running and MainActivity is running, open MainActivity (this is easy, there are planty of ways I can to that with various flags) but if it's not running launch StartActivity (so that I can open the app based on all the startup logics implemented there).

So the options I can think of are:

- know if an activity is running in order to fire an intent or another (I don't like static fields solutions like you read in many SO post related to this)
- make StartActivity the root of the task and find a combination of intent flags which will act like "launch StartActivity, but if it is running at the root of a task, bring that task to front" (this would be my preferred option if possible)
- any suggestion is very appreciated

How do you usually handle this kind of situations? (I don't think I'm the first in the world with this problem :) )

Comment: What I understood is you want to know if there is an activity running or not? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes, that's one of the options, but is not the best solution. Every thread speaking about detecting if an activity is running, the solution at the end is a static field

Comment: Are you familiar with `onNewIntent()` ?

Comment: Yes, I know how to use that method, but what I want is a suggestion about which is the best way to handle my situation

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach -

Make `StartActivity` as your router as you've said. Just make launchmode to `singleTop` in your manifest in order to user `onNewIntent()` method of an `Activity`.

You'll generate notification, sending some data with `contentIntent` - as a result clicking on notification you'll be redirected to `StartActivity`.

Two cases here -

- **If `StartActivity` is in stack**

   `onNewIntent` gets called with your new Intent - Choose your activity required to be open - 
  If it is already in stack Bring it to front using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag
- **If `StartActivity` is not running or not in stack**

   Receive `bundle` of `intent` that is being got from the intent via notification, parse data and open an activity accordingly.